# Amazon S3 - set Region to EU using Java AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am in Europe.
How do I set the Region to EU (ireland) when using AmazonS3Client to copy files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Amazon S3 Region enum is very helpful for looking up the different Amazon S3 endpoints:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/Region.html

After you find the right endpoint for EU, just call setEndpoint on your AmazonS3 client object.

Comment: I asked for the wrong question, sorry.
I should have asked  how to change the region using Java.

The solution I found to choose the region is:

        'CreateBucketRequest req = new CreateBucketRequest(name, Region.EU_Ireland);
        
        s3.createBucket(req);'